Request and response model not loading on swagger UI when migrating from swagger 1.2 to swagger 2.0
Q&A (please complete the following information)

OS: macos
Browser: chrome
Version: 130.0.6723.117
Method of installation: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/installation/#unpkg
Swagger-UI version: 5.11.0
Swagger/OpenAPI version: Swagger 2.0

Content & configuration
I am migrating from swagger 1.2 to swagger 2.0 spec. My APIs are configured in this way
@ApiOperation(value = "Get user", notes = "get user", response = User.class)
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = RestConstant.STATUS_CODE_400, message = "Invalid User Input"),
            @ApiResponse(code = RestConstant.STATUS_CODE_500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
    @Override
    @GZIP
    @Path("/{number}")
    @PUT
    public Response getUser( @ApiParam(value = "Profile object with hostname", required = true) User user,
            @PathParam("accountNumber") String number) {


Swagger/OpenAPI definition:
My schema for request and response is coming as null
"User": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {

      },
      "xml": {
        "name": "user"
      }
    }

Swagger-UI configuration options:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="SwaggerUI" />
  <title>SwaggerUI</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5.11.0/swagger-ui.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="swagger-ui"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5.11.0/swagger-ui-bundle.js" crossorigin></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5.11.0/swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js" crossorigin></script>
<script>
  window.onload = () => {
    window.ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
      url: 'restservices/swagger.json',
      dom_id: '#swagger-ui',
      presets: [
        SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
        SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
      ],
      layout: "StandaloneLayout",
    });
  };
</script>
</body>
</html>

How can we help?
I didn't use  @ApiModel and @ApiModelProperty with swagger 1.2 and swagger was able to generate schema, but now it is broken. So is it compulsory now? Also I am generating model classes from xsd files, please provide a doc on how to annotate  that?

There was addition of a new method in SwaggerSpecFilter interface - isPropertyAllowed. I was returning by default false which was not loading properties in swagger.json. Changed it to true and its working fine!
